# Problem with limits when using polar coordinates:

Tags: limits, proof-verification, problem-solving

If I did the following limit using x = rcos  y = rsin I find that the limit goes to 0. Doesn't that prove that the limit does not exist since I found 2 different limits ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{ r\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 3{ r }^{ 2 } }{ \sqrt { { r }^{ 2 }+4 } -2 }  } =\lim _{ r\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 3{ r }^{ 2 }\left( \sqrt { { r }^{ 2 }+4 } +2 \right)  }{ { r }^{ 2 } }  } =12$$

Answer (score 1):

When you make the transformation, you should get

$\displaystyle \lim_{r \to 0}
\frac{3r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+4}-2} $.

Now conjugate the denominator to get $\displaystyle \lim_{r \to 0}
\frac{3r^2\left(\sqrt{r^2+4}+2\right)}{r^2}=\displaystyle \lim_{r \to 0}
3(\sqrt{r^2+4}+2) =\boxed{12}$

Comment: Use the fact that if $r\cos(\theta)=x$, and $r\sin(\theta)=y$, $x^2+y^2=r^2$

Comment: and you don't need to worry about multiple limits when your entire function is in terms of $r$ because the polar function measures the distance, so as r approaches 0, you approach from ALL direction

Comment: if a function is not differentiable at Ø=2π
would you say
360 no slope

Comment: but can I get r out in the denominator to get 3r/(1)?

Comment: I got : $\frac{3r^{2}}{r(\sqrt[]{1+\frac{4}{r^{2}}}-\frac{2}{r})}$

which tends to 0 ?

Comment: So where did the 4/(r^2) and the 2/r come from?

Comment: @SoHCahToha $4/r^2$ and $-2/r$ will be infinities of opposite signs when $r \rightarrow 0$, so that doesn't really work